# How to search string in NSOutlineView using Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsoutlineview

[image: plist data]I have OutlineView with plist(dictionary) data. I want to add search functionality to it. I have added a search-bar for user input. Once user enter some string and click on search button, searched item shout get selected in the OutlineView

I tried searching for some tutorials but no help.

Comment: Search the data for the string and select the corresponding item. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Willeke, Actually I have plist which consists Dictionary inside array inside dictionary. I am confused how to iterate each and every root item and make it selected item in outlineview. Attaching plist data in the question.

Comment: How is the plist converted to items?

Comment: @Willeke first storing values into array and displaying same using OutlineView delegate methods.

Answer (score 1):

I have found some helpful tutorials and able to search string in the outlineView.

```
    let userInput  = txtSearchField.stringValue
    guard let outlineView = myOutlineView else { return }

    var itemIndex: Int = outlineView.row(forItem: userInput)
    let value = outlineView.item(atRow: itemIndex)
    
    if itemIndex < 0 {
        //if item is not available in the outlineView
        
    }
    print("Expanding row", itemIndex)
    outlineView.selectRowIndexes(IndexSet(integer: itemIndex), byExtendingSelection: .init(true))
    outlineView.scrollRowToVisible(itemIndex)
```